# Calling program silently from system()

Tags: r

I am calling an external program using the system() command in R as follows

`system(r"{"C:\\Program Files\\EViews 13\\EViews13.exe" exec "C:\\Users\\LDD\\SimulateMod.prg"}")`

Which works fine, but the EViews GUI application is launched. What I would like to do is call this program so it runs without launching the GUI.

If I run this using CMD, and use the command /programonly, this works.

`"C:\\Program Files\\EViews 13\\EViews13.exe"/programonly exec "C:\\Users\\LDD\\SimulateMod.prg"`

However, passing /programonly to the system() command does not.

I would expect the program "SimulateMod.prg" to executed using the application EViews13.exe without the applications GUI launching, which is the behaviour I experience when using /programonly in the CMD prompt.

Comment: You could try the newer `system2`, passing the /programonly switch an possibly other options like so: `system2("path/to/your/program.exe", args = "/programonly")`. You could additionallly set `minimized = TRUE`: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/system2 (see an overview over how to call system commands here: https://ropensci.org/blog/2021/09/13/system-calls-r-package/)